# resultado de consulta sem refresh JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Aloha, quando o cliente entrar na minha aplicação ele vai ver um form pra agendamento, tem alguma forma de passar as informações sem dar refresh?
quando o cliente selecionar o dia, mostra o horário de funcionamento, depois de escolher o horário, só mostrar os funcionários com a agenda disponível.

FORM:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo pg.'/arquivos/registra_agendamento.php';?>">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 grid-margin stretch-card">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
     <div class="charts-data">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Data:</label>
           <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="dia" data-inputmask="'alias': 'date'" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Hora: </label>
           <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="hora">
              <option value=""></option>
              <?php
                 $query_hora = "SELECT * FROM funcionamento ORDER BY hora ASC";
                 $result_hora = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_hora);
                 while ($linhas_hora = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_hora)){
                   $hora = $linhas_hora['hora'];
                   echo "
                     <option value='".$hora."'>".$hora.":00</option>
                   ";
                 }
                 ?>                      
           </select>
        </div>
        <?php
           if(o input dia == $hoje){
           $query_agenda = "SELECT * FROM agendamento WHERE dia='o input dia' AND hora='$hora'";
            $result_agenda = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_agenda);
            while ($linhas_agenda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_agenda)){
            $agendado = $linhas_agenda['func'];

            $query_fun = "SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE nome!='$agendado' AND nivel='3' AND estado='1' AND atend='1' ORDER BY nome ASC";
            $result_fun = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_fun);
            while ($linhas_fun = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_fun)){
            $fun_nome = $linhas_fun['nome'];
            $img_fun = pg.'/images/funcionarios/'.$linhas_fun['img'].'.jpg';
               echo "
                 <div class='d-flex align-items-center py-3 border-bottom'>
                   <img class='img-sm rounded-circle' src='".$img_fun."' alt='".$fun_nome."'>
                   <div class='ml-3'>
                     <h5 class='mb-1 font-weight-bold'>".$fun_nome."</h5>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               ";
             }}
           }else{
           $query_agenda = "SELECT * FROM agendamento WHERE dia='$dia' AND hora='$hora'";
            $result_agenda = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_agenda);
            while ($linhas_agenda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_agenda)){
            $agendado = $linhas_agenda['func'];

            $query_fun = "SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE nome!='$agendado' AND nivel='3' AND estado='1' ORDER BY nome ASC";
            $result_fun = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_fun);
            while ($linhas_fun = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_fun)){
            $fun_nome = $linhas_fun['nome'];
            $img_fun = pg.'/images/funcionarios/'.$linhas_fun['img'].'.jpg';
            echo "
                 <div class='d-flex align-items-center py-3 border-bottom'>
                   <img class='img-sm rounded-circle' src='".$img_fun."' alt='".$fun_nome."'>
                   <div class='ml-3'>
                     <h5 class='mb-1 font-weight-bold'>".$fun_nome."</h5>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               ";
             }}
           }
           ?>
        <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="obs" name="obs" placeholder="Obs">
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-center">
           <button type='submit' class="btn btn-dark btn-rounded btn-fw">Agendar</button></a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer essa atualização sem dar refresh utilizando jquery e ajax. 
Primeiro, no **select de seleção de hora** você acrescenta uma chamada para uma função (*VerificarDisponivel*) javascript passando o valor do próprio select como parâmetro, a estrutura da página do seu form ficaria assim:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo pg.'/arquivos/registra_agendamento.php';?>">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 grid-margin stretch-card">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
     <div class="charts-data">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Data:</label>
           <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="dia" data-inputmask="'alias': 'date'" id="dataAgenda" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Hora: </label>
           <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="hora" onchange="VerificarDisponivel(this.value);">
              <option value=""></option>
              <?php
                 $query_hora = "SELECT * FROM funcionamento ORDER BY hora ASC";
                 $result_hora = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_hora);
                 while ($linhas_hora = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_hora)){
                   $hora = $linhas_hora['hora'];
                   echo "
                     <option value='".$hora."'>".$hora.":00</option>
                   ";
                 }
                 ?>                      
           </select>
        </div>

        <div id="resposta"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="obs" name="obs" placeholder="Obs">
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-center">
           <button type='submit' class="btn btn-dark btn-rounded btn-fw">Agendar</button></a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Agora existe uma **div com id resposta** onde será atualizado as informações vindo do banco de dados.
A função javascript **VerificaDisponivel** ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
function VerificarDisponivel(hora){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "agendamento.php",
        data: {'hora': hora , 'dataAgenda' : $('#dataAgenda').val()},
        success: function(html){
            $('#resposta').html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

E por fim, o arquivo **agendamento.php** que será responsável por consultar no banco de dados as informações devolver as informações da maneira que você quiser:

```
$hora = $_POST['hora'];
$dataAgenda = $_POST['dataAgenda'];

if($dataAgenda == $hoje){
   $query_agenda = "SELECT * FROM agendamento WHERE dia='o input dia' AND hora='$hora'";
    $result_agenda = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_agenda);
    while ($linhas_agenda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_agenda)){
    $agendado = $linhas_agenda['func'];

    $query_fun = "SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE nome!='$agendado' AND nivel='3' AND estado='1' AND atend='1' ORDER BY nome ASC";
    $result_fun = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_fun);
    while ($linhas_fun = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_fun)){
    $fun_nome = $linhas_fun['nome'];
    $img_fun = pg.'/images/funcionarios/'.$linhas_fun['img'].'.jpg';
       echo "
         <div class='d-flex align-items-center py-3 border-bottom'>
           <img class='img-sm rounded-circle' src='".$img_fun."' alt='".$fun_nome."'>
           <div class='ml-3'>
             <h5 class='mb-1 font-weight-bold'>".$fun_nome."</h5>
           </div>
         </div>
       ";
     }}
 }else{
   $query_agenda = "SELECT * FROM agendamento WHERE dia='$dia' AND hora='$hora'";
    $result_agenda = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_agenda);
    while ($linhas_agenda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_agenda)){
    $agendado = $linhas_agenda['func'];

    $query_fun = "SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE nome!='$agendado' AND nivel='3' AND estado='1' ORDER BY nome ASC";
    $result_fun = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_fun);
    while ($linhas_fun = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_fun)){
    $fun_nome = $linhas_fun['nome'];
    $img_fun = pg.'/images/funcionarios/'.$linhas_fun['img'].'.jpg';
    echo "
         <div class='d-flex align-items-center py-3 border-bottom'>
           <img class='img-sm rounded-circle' src='".$img_fun."' alt='".$fun_nome."'>
           <div class='ml-3'>
             <h5 class='mb-1 font-weight-bold'>".$fun_nome."</h5>
           </div>
         </div>
       ";
     }}
   }
```

Comment: eu apliquei as correções, coloquei o <script> a cima da div 'resposta', criei o arquivo agendamento.php (iniciei a session, incluir a conexao.php e inclui a data do $hoje) ainda sim não imprime nenhuma informação na div 'resposta'. o que pode ser ?

Comment: @RonaldodeLima faz o seguinte, altere a função **VerificarDisponivel**: embaixo da linha `$('#reposta').html(html);`adicione `console.dir(html);` para verificar se o **agendamento.php** está retornando algo.

Comment: no onchange ou no script?

Comment: @RonaldodeLima no script

Comment: não retornou nada

Comment: @RonaldodeLima tem que ver no **agendamento.php**, tenta tirar todo o código e colocar um select simples, sem if, sem nada só pra retornar algo, ai você vai construindo.

Comment: tirei tudo e deixei apenas um echo $hora e $dataAgenda. ainda não imprimiu nada

Comment: testei de varias formas, a propósito to usando url amigável, tem influencia?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96030/discussion-between-guto-xavier-and-ronaldo-de-lima).